# Can I use NSDateFormatter to convert this date string to an NSDate?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have this string...

```
2010-08-24T16:00:00-05:00
```

and I'd like to extract the time portion from it (i.e. 16:00) and convert it to its 12-hour equivalent (i.e. 04:00 pm).  I'm trying to use NSDateFormatter to accomplish this, but it's not working...

```
NSDateFormatter* dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSDate *date1 = [dateformatter dateFromString:[listOfTimes objectAtIndex:0]];
[dateformatter release];
```

Can I use NSDateFormatter with this date format?  If not, how can I extract the time and convert it to its 12-hour time equivalent?

Thanks!

Comment: Please supply your current non-working code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has to do with parsing the colon. I asked the same question and the solution is here: [How to parse a date string into an NSDate object in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999396/how-to-parse-a-date-string-into-an-nsdate-object-in-ios)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to do something like the following.

```
    // create the date formatter object 
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate* date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
    // set up the new date format
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
    NSString *twelveHourTime = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    [formatter release];
```

Update: Fixed the dateFormatter string format. I had the line below, but the Z seems to be unnecessary. Timezones always screw me up. :-/

```
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
```

Comment: hmmm...that didn't work, but it looks good to me.  the date returned from [formatter dateFromString:dateString] returns an invalid string.

Comment: thanks, Jerry, but still no. I get back an <invalid CFStringRef>.  out of curiosity, have you tested this and it works?  i'm wondering if i'm doing something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry, I seem to be having a hard time transposing code today. I tested SOMETHING that worked, it was definitely not this.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that I can't find a way to support the colon in the timezone offset.

Answer (score 0):

This answer needs to be updated. As of iOS 10 the system provided [NSISO8601DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsiso8601dateformatter?language=objc) is available for this particular format.