# How do I get the NSString date part from @"2011-11-22 03:20:39"?

Tags: ios, nsstring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSString to NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353081/nsstring-to-nsdate)
>   [How to parse a date string into an NSDate object in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999396/how-to-parse-a-date-string-into-an-nsdate-object-in-ios)

I have NSString *dateAndTime = @"2011-11-22 03:20:39".

I want to get a NSString *dateWithoutTime (e.g. "2011-11-22") from this above string.

How do I get?

Comment: this question gets asked [so very often](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353081/nsstring-to-nsdate)

Comment: **I want to get NSString *date from this string.** - Read more carefully. He don't want to get NSDate

Comment: drat!  I can't cancel my close vote.  I'll edit it to make the question more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
NSString *dateAndTime = @"2011-11-22 03:20:39";
NSString *date = [[dateAndTime componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the corresponding `NSDate` by

```
NSString *dateString = @"2011-11-22 03:20:39";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormat release];
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

But this has been answered so many times. Search the previous posts before asking a new question.