# sorting string Array

Tags: arrays, ios5

I have a txt file (string) with elements separated with ";". I an reading this into an MSMutable array. I need to sort on the field following the date. It will be integer data. How do I grab this field out of the string in order to sort it. I have searched for days and cannot find a reference to this.

2012/09/17;5;-54.74
2012/09/17;76;6.53
2012/09/17;66;6.53
2012/09/17;69;6.53
2012/09/17;60;6.53
2012/09/17;96;6.53
2012/09/17;86;6.53
2012/09/17;77;6.53

Thanks,

Ron

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sortUsingComparator:` method, like this:

```
[array sortUsingComparator: ^(id lhs, id rhs) {
    // Get the string between the first and the second semicolons:
    NSString *obj1 = [[lhs componentsSeparatedByString:@";"] objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString *obj2 = [[rhs componentsSeparatedByString:@";"] objectAtIndex:1];
    // Compare the two strings as integers:
    if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Comment: Thanks, I am new at this. Let me give it a try

Comment: This works great but how do i sort on the date field. I cannot get it to select a date object

Comment: @RonBledsoe `objectAtIndex:0` will give you the date string. Parse it ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4999396/335858)) and compare them for sorting.