# Parse Date from string

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am not able to parse the following string into date

```
2012-12-28T00:01:51Z ,

I need date in format 28 Dec 2012
```

Please help me .

Thanks in advance 
Abhishek

Comment: Is Comma there in the string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a date string into an NSDate object in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999396/how-to-parse-a-date-string-into-an-nsdate-object-in-ios)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
NSString *dateString=@"2012-12-28T00:01:51Z";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'"];

NSLog(@"=> time %@",[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString]);

NSDate *formattedDate=[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM YYYY"];
NSLog(@"Formatted date : %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:formattedDate]);
```

Comment: Thank you soo much and perfect one... exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

Why dont u pass the string simply as it is and then convert it into any format u want ?

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
```

Comment: It wont work, as the input string in not is proper date format.