# NSDateFormatter Not Formatting String

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I have the following code which is being called in cellForRowAtIndexPath for a UITableView.

```
self.dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[self.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];

OLVisit *visit = [self.visits objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *strVisitDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", visit.olcreatedat];
NSDate *visitDate = [self.dateFormatter dateFromString:strVisitDate];
strVisitDate = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:visitDate];
```

The string returned from visit.olcreatedat is in the following format (as can be seen in the debugger screenshot below) "2013-04-09 11:55:25 +0000".

[image]

I get a nil NSDate value returned into visitDate.

Could somebody help me figure this out?

Comment: Maybe if you set the date format to match the format of the date you'd have better luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a date string into an NSDate object in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999396/how-to-parse-a-date-string-into-an-nsdate-object-in-ios)

Comment: What is the type of `visit.olcreatedat`? Is it an `NSString`? If so, get rid of the call to `stringWithFormat:`.

Comment: @HotLicks that link also helps and I had previously read through it before posting but it does not solve the problem I have of getting the date formatted into the format of "EEEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"

Comment: @rmaddy visit.olcreatedat is in my visit entity defined as an Date data type.  I am pulling back this field from core data in the scenario above.

Comment: @motionpotion Is it's already an `NSDate`, then why do you convert to a string and then back to another date? All you need to do is call `[self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:visit.olcreatedat];` and you are done. Get rid of `strVisitDate` and `visitDate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**: As pointed out by @rmaddy, there was a misunderstanding about what `visit.olcreatedat` was. 
This first answer is based on the assumption that `visit.olcreatedat` is an
NSDate. For an answer that assumes that `visit.olcreatedat` is an NSString containing a formatted date, read the second part of this answer.

## visit.olcreatedat is an NSDate

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Alloc the date formatter in a method that gets run only when the controller appears, and not during scroll operations or UI updates.
    self.outputDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [self.outputDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];
}


- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath: {
   // dequeue or create the cell... 
   // ...
   // ...

   OLVisit *visit = [self.visits objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   NSString * strVisitDate = [self.outputDateFormatter stringFromDate:visit.olcreatedat];

   // Here you can assign the string to the right UILabel
   cell.textLabel.text = strVisitDate;

   return cell;
}
```

## visit.olcreatedat is an NSString

Do you want to convert the `visit.olcreatedat` to the format **EEEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z**? If so, let's go through each step.

First, you need to convert the  `visit.olcreatedat` string (stored in `strVisitDate`) to an actual NSDate object, `visitDate`. So to make this step work, you need an NSDateFormatter that accepts the `visit.olcreatedat` format: **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z**.

Then, you want to convert the obtained `visitDate` NSDate to the format you like, so you need another NSDateFormatter, with the format **EEEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z**.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Alloc the date formatter in a method that gets run only when the controller appears, and not during scroll operations or UI updates.
    self.inputDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [self.inputDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];
    self.outputDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [self.outputDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath: {
   // dequeue or create the cell... 
   // ...
   // ...

   OLVisit *visit = [self.visits objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   NSString *strVisitDate = visit.olcreatedat;
   NSDate *visitDate = [self.inputDateFormatter dateFromString:strVisitDate];
   strVisitDate = [self.outputDateFormatter stringFromDate:visitDate];

   // Here you can assign the string to the right UILabel
   cell.textLabel.text = strVisitDate;

   return cell;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to do.  Thank you so much for all responses.

Comment: Just a side note: avoid to allocate many NSDateFormatter or to change their date format if you need fast responses, since it is an heavy operation to do. If you do that in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` for example you could have sluggy performances. In that case, use one or more static NSDateFormatter instead, or reuse the same NSDateFormatter stored in a property, as you are doing here.

Comment: thanks for the extra tip.  It looks like I am doing it correctly then by setting NSDateFormatter as a property on my ViewController.

Comment: Yes, but are you assigning the date formatter to that property in viewDidLoad or init method?

Comment: no I am assigning the date formatter to the property each time I need to use it ... in this case in the cellForRowAtIndexPath.  I am using it elsewhere in other methods in the View controller but each time I set it.  I presume you mean that I should set it once in the init or viewDidLoad and then reuse it elsewhere without setting it again.

Comment: I see your example now.  Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Exactly, you should just set it once in the lifetime of the controller . You're welcome.

Comment: Much of this code is pointless since `visit.olcreatedat` is already an `NSDate` object. There is no reason to convert the `NSDate` to an `NSString` using `stringWithFormat:`, then to convert that string back to a new `NSDate` (especially since the format of the string is not documented and has changed in the past).

Comment: @rmaddy I don't know if olcreatedat is an NSDate or a NSString containing a formatted date, @motionpotion didn't specified that. I assumed that it is an NSString. If it is an NSDate you are absolutely right, and obviously @motionpotion just needs the outputDateFormatter, using just `[self.outputDateFormatter stringFromDate:visit.olcreatedat]`

Comment: The OP mentioned that it's a date in the reply to my question about what type it was. See the 5th comment below the question.

Comment: Oh ok, it has been written while I was writing my answer or after that :) I update my answer now, to reflect this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

change your date format and replace code :

**Old :**

```
[self.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];
```

**New :**

```
[self.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];
```

This is because you are using different date format while strVisitDate date format is "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z".
So you need to set the same format.

Edit :

Replace your code with this.

```
self.dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[self.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];

OLVisit *visit = [self.visits objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *strVisitDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", visit.olcreatedat];

NSDate *visitDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strVisitDate];
strVisitDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:visitDate];

//Here you can set any date Format as per your need

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];
strVisitDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:visitDate];
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: That helped a lot and it works but how do I then get the date into the format that I need "EEEE, dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss z".

I need it to output to a UILabel in that specific format.

Comment: @NishantTyagi, just a side note: changing the dateFormat is an heavy operation. If you do that in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` for example you could have sluggy scroll performance, so it is better to have a separate NSDateFormatter instance with the right format.

Comment: @AlessandroOrrù do you have an example of where I should perform this date formatting outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath?  I am currently performing this in this method.  I am only returning a few cells at the moment but will eventually be returning thousands potentially depending on filter selected by users.

Comment: @motionpotion I have updated my answer with an example, look at it