# Parsing EXIF date string to NSDate

Tags: ios

The input date string I need to parse is 2013:05:14 13:24:44
I try with this NSDateFormatter code but it does not work...
Any idea ?

```
_dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter alloc];
[_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy:MM:dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[_dateFormatter setLocale:usLocale];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999396/how-to-parse-a-date-string-into-an-nsdate-object-in-ios?rq=1

Comment: show the date string.

Comment: no date string, no expected output, no actual output, meaningless "it does not work" - not a real question

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `hh:mm:ss` in the string, you need `HH:mm:ss`.  Since the string shows "13" for the hour, you need to use `HH` (00-23) instead of `hh` (01-12).

Comment: Actually, he needs to read the spec for NSDateFormatter and follow the links to the info on format strings.

Comment: I have tried your recommandation (HH:mm:ss) but it does not work as well.. I think the issue is more on the date section (yyyy:MM:dd)