# NSDateFormatter dateFromString returns nil for parsing EXIF data

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to parse data from EXIF date to `NSDate`. Here is a sample date string taken from an image file:

`2013:10:15 19:19:31`

It is in `year:month:day 24hour:minute:second` format. I am using the following code to parse this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormat:@"yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss" allowNaturalLanguage:YES];
formatter.formatterBehavior = NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4;
formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dt];
```

If I don't set the formatter behavior it complains about trying a locale identifier of 10.4 on an 10.0 formatter. (I'm on Mavericks, I think it's a new issue on Mavericks) Anyway I've tried combinations of not setting locale at all, setting locale to `en_US_POSIX` instead of just `en_US`, setting a timezone for formatter, changing `yyyy` to `YYYY` in date format, and `allowNaturalLanguage` to `NO`, however, `dateFromString` *always* returns nil. My app is running on OS X Mavericks, my system's language is English, and my region is set to Turkey if it matters. I want my app to be English-only, independent of users' region (including the date formats). I've seen this question: [Parsing EXIF date string to NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568261/parsing-exif-date-string-to-nsdate) but even I try the exact steps, formatter returns nil for `dateFromString`. What is wrong with the date formatter?

Comment: it worked. weird. it looks like a bug in the formatter. could you please post this as an answer so I can accept it, with any possible explanation for this weird behavior of date formatter (if any)?

Comment: It looks like you were doing everything correctly -- no explanation, other that gremlins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a problem of the `initWithDateFormat` initializer.
According to the documentation, it creates a formatter that uses the "OS X v10.0 formatting behavior", but I have no idea what that is. And setting the behavior to `NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4` explicitly seems also not to help.

Using

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"2013:10:15 19:19:31"];
```

produces the expected result.

Comment: It would also be a good idea to report this as a bug to Apple. I'll be doing it now.