# how to convert date to string like this "2013-12-23T12:02:01+05:30"

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have string "2013-12-23T12:02:01+05:30"
i want to convert into date but i am getting NSDate nil
here is my code

```
        // Convert string to date object
        NSString *dateStr = @"2013-12-23T12:02:01+05:30";
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy, MM DD 'T' HH:mm:ss Z"];
        NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a date string into an NSDate object in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999396/how-to-parse-a-date-string-into-an-nsdate-object-in-ios)

Comment: the formatter `@"yyyy, MM DD 'T' HH:mm:ss Z"` is incorrect in so many ways for string `@"2013-12-23T12:02:01+05:30"`... probably that causes a `nil` value.

Comment: thnx @MatthiasBauch, i got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string format does not match you date string:

```
    NSString *dateStr = @"2013-12-23T12:02:01+05:30";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

In you example date sting there are `-` used in the date, in the format you are using uses . Also `DD` will give you the day in the year not in the month. and there is no space after the seconds and time zone offset.

Comment: Date will always be present with the GMT time zone. When you present a date to the user use `NSDateFormatter` and set the correct time zone.

Comment: how to set time zone of incomeing string?

Comment: i am using [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

after allocation of date formatter

Comment: When parsing a date without a time zone the time zone set is used. But in your example the date has a time zone. `NSDateFormatter` will parse this time zone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the correct date format to match with the date string

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2013-12-23T12:02:01+05:30";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

Comment: The `DD` in your time stamp will not work, since `DD` will should give you the day of the year not month.