# NSDateFormatter can't parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have searched throughout.
I need to parse a date string as:
NSString * dateString = @"2014-01-14T10:10:44.497Z"

I need the day as mon, tue, wed etc.

I can't get any formatter to convert the date am getting.

any help ?

Thanks in Advance

**code that i have been using :**

NSString * time = @"2014-01-14T10:10:44.497Z";

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];






NSDate *date1 =[self dateFromISO8601String:time]; //[df dateFromString:time];

NSLog(@"date : %@", date1);

long lgTime = (long)[date1 timeIntervalSince1970];
NSLog(@"%ld", lgTime);


NSCalendar* calender = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* component = [calender components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date1];

NSLog(@"date=%@ === %@",[NSDate date],date1);
NSLog(@"day= %d",[component weekday]); ///it retu
```

**response in console:**
**error**

2014-01-14 17:42:23.790 TextDate[2847:a0b] date send : 2014-01-14T10:10:44.497Z

2014-01-14 17:42:23.790 TextDate[2847:a0b] date : (null)

2014-01-14 17:42:23.791 TextDate[2847:a0b] 0

2014-01-14 17:42:23.794 TextDate[2847:a0b] *** -[__NSCFCalendar components:fromDate:]: date cannot be nil

I mean really, what do you think that operation is supposed to mean with a nil date?

Comment: What _do_ you get? What have you tried?

Comment: Show us the code you're using.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it fails to describe a problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999396/how-to-parse-a-date-string-into-an-nsdate-object-in-ios

Comment: i have edited the question.. with more details.

Comment: @HotLicks instead of giving offtopic remarks .. help me out..

Comment: Well, you have to help yourself first.  We can't imagine what you might have written.  But now that you've deigned to show us the code, enclose the Z character in single quotes, so it's not taken as a timezone formatting character.

Comment: And add ".SSS" after the "ss" to pick up the fractional seconds.  And bookmark the [date formatting pattern doc](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use two-date formatters.

First to change string to date.

Second to convert date to string in form of Sun/Mon etc.

```
NSString * dateString = @"2014-01-14T10:10:44.497Z";

NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'.'SSS'Z'"];

NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:dateString];

[df setDateFormat:@"EEE"];

NSLog(@"%@",[df stringFromDate:date]);
```

Comment: trying it in a min and replying

Comment: Thanks it is done. I have not done any formatting using the 
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'.'SS'Z'" 

speacially the . thing was new. thans it worked

Comment: @ManiacOne - Like I said above, bookmark the date format spec, so you can figure out these things on your own.  (And it should be "SSS", not "SS".)

Comment: @HotLicks: I agree... updated :)