# CoreData/Swift 2 having Trouble Saving NSDate type

Tags: core-data, swift2

I'm having trouble saving the date type in xcode 7. the error says you cannot assign a string? to NSDate? so is there another way to save the NSDate type instead of what I'm doing? Also for the datefield I made a datepicker pragmatically for it to input text into it, I don't know if that makes a difference or not.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var dateField: UITextField!
@IBAction func dateField(sender: UITextField) {

    // This creates an Input View
    let inputView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, 240))

    // This creates an Picker View for the date
    let datePickerView : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0))
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
    inputView.addSubview(datePickerView)

    // Makes a toolbar with  a done button at the top of of the date picker view for it to dismiss the moment its clicked
    let doneButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2) - (100/2), 0, 100, 50))
    doneButton.setTitle("Done", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    doneButton.setTitle("Done", forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
    doneButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    doneButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.grayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)

    // Adds the done button to the datepicker
    inputView.addSubview(doneButton)
    doneButton.addTarget(self, action: "doneButton:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    // Uses the date picker as a date picker using the format made in the function 'datePickerChanged'
    sender.inputView = inputView
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datePickerChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    // Immediately sets a date on start
    datePickerChanged(datePickerView)

}


func doneButton(sender : UIButton) {
    dateField.resignFirstResponder()
}

func datePickerChanged(sender : UIDatePicker) {
    // Creates a date sytle format for the date picker
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
    dateField.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
}
```

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999396/how-to-parse-a-date-string-into-an-nsdate-object-in-ios

Comment: that didn't really help me, I have my code coming in from a UITextfield, and  I have the user entering the date in there using a datepickerview that I made so I need to save it from there. Also I'm using swift not Objective-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - *I won't ask why you use a DatePicker to put a date in a textField and then convert the text from the textField to a date again*.

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = /*Use the same format as is output by your datepicker*/
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(/*your_date_string*/)
```