# Convert NSDate to JSON Date?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, nsdate

I need to post a `NSDate` object using HTTP post to parse.com.
I don't know how to convert it.

```
//1  nsdate
[params setObject:date forKey:kKeyDate];

//2 nsstring
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd T HH : mm : ss.SSSZ"];
 NSString *newString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
 [params setObject:newString forKey:kKeyDate];
```

*Params are serialized in the body of the Http request. I know that everything else I'm doing is correct because if I comment out adding the `NSDate` to the params, then it works.*

Comment: Can this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999396/how-to-parse-a-date-string-into-an-nsdate-object-in-ios

Comment: I don't get it, if second option works then what is the issue?

Comment: Use `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"`

Answer (score 4):

try this ..

```
NSDate *CurrentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *DATEFORMATER = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[DATEFORMATER setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.SSS'Z'"];
[DATEFORMATER setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
NSString *DATE_STRING = [DATEFORMATER stringFromDate:CurrentDate];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using iOS 10.0 or above, use the ISO8601DateFormatter class.

Comment: I recommend that you do _not_ use ISO8601DateFormatter, as it fails when the time has milliseconds. http://www.openradar.me/29609526

Comment: After almost 3 years and the radar is  open !

Answer (score 1):

According to the `Parse.com` [documentation](https://www.parse.com/questions/how-do-add-a-date-using-a-rest-post-request):

```
{
    "__type": "Date",
    "iso": "2011-08-21T18:02:52.249Z"
}
```

**Obj-C**

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSString *newString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
[params setObject:newString forKey:kKeyDate];
```